# Ajax cart discount on shopify

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, cart, shopping-cart

I was wondering how I can show the already discounted price on the cart. My website has a discount popup that shows up after a few seconds and generates a discount automatically, the client then activates it but it does not show in the cart on the side, only after initiating the checkout. I already searched on the community but I can't seem to find a proper answer. I also attached two images with how it looks right now and how I would like it to show. Thank you very much!

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emYeT.jpg)     [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAyUn.jpg)

Comment: How are you discounting the products in the cart? Are you using an app or anything like that?

Comment: @DaveB I am not discounting them in the cart, that is what I would like to do. I use an app that generates 10% discount code when the client enters his email. After they enter the email, the discount code applies to the order, but it doesn't show until they go to checkout, and I would like the discounted price to appear in the cart too, because I feel like some percentage between ATC and CR is lost because of this.

Comment: Hmm. This could be tricky, as Shopify only applies discounts to Checkouts, not to Carts (even though a cart object is turned into a checkout object when you enter the checkout pages). There's no easy way to get a 'live' discounted price before you reach the checkout, but if you are okay with doing some hard-coding you could probably do something to 'fake it'.  The change would be visual-only and if you ever changed your newsletter discount you would have to update your visual display code to match... would that work for you, though?

Comment: @DaveB that is what I was thinking too, to somehow force it into the cart's interface and fake it, that would definitely work for me. May I contact you regarding this?

Comment: @DaveB Would you be up for helping me with this?

Comment: Sure! Do you know what theme you are using?

Comment: Yes, Shella is the theme I'm using